# JGit Not cloning all branches

Tags: java, spring, jgit

JGit is not letting me clone all branches to local.

Heres my code which clones the repo.

```
git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(repositoryURL)
    .setCredentialsProvider(cp)
    .setDirectory(file)
    .setCloneAllBranches(true)
    .call();
```

Just after cloning, I'm printing the list of local + remote branches using the code below

```
System.out.println("Showing local branches...");
List<Ref> call = git.branchList().call();
for (Ref ref : call) {
    System.out.println("Branch: " + ref.getName());
}

System.out.println("Now including remote branches:");
call = git.branchList().setListMode(ListMode.ALL).call();
for (Ref ref : call) {
    System.out.println("Branch: " + ref.getName());
}
```

This is the output I'm getting..... as you can see, local branches is just showing the master branch.

```
Showing local branches...

Branch: refs/heads/master

Now including remote branches:

Branch: refs/heads/master
Branch: refs/remotes/origin/docker
Branch: refs/remotes/origin/master
Branch: refs/remotes/origin/release
Branch: refs/remotes/origin/stage
```

Would I have to manually issue branch creation command for each of the remote branches?

Comment: You have the remote refs. Why do you need more?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I want to auto-checkout branch using jgit. Because it's not present locally, its throwing an exception. Do I have to initialize them first manually using refs?

Comment: What you describe is normal behavior for a non-specific clone. Considered telling jgit to check out the branch you need?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen maybe I misunderstood the call setCloneAllBranches. I thought it would clone all branches and create them locally.

So to solve my question, I should manually create local branches using the refs after cloning?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how git works.  After a clone all branches known to the repository - local and remote - can be checked out, but only one at a time.