# JGIT checkout remote branch for repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, jgit

Trying to checkout remote branches for repository:

Command: `git.checkout().setCreateBranch(true).setName(<branchName>).setUpstreamMode(CreateBranchCommand.SetupUpstreamMode.TRACK).call()`

However, it is setting the new branch HEAD at changes from `master` branch in local.

The git command I need to recreate
`git checkout -b <branchName>` - Where head of new branch should be same as head of remote

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JGit: Checkout a remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927163/jgit-checkout-a-remote-branch)

Comment: No, I had to change my code to download all branches when I clone my repo. It seems if the local doesn't have reference of remote branch, it is not able to checkout with the command in the given answer

Comment: In order to check out a remote branch it needs to be present in the local repository. Note, that this is a concept of Git and not specific to JGit. To make remote branches available locally you need to fetch (clone = init + fetch) them first.

Comment: How to fetch remote branches in my local repo from jgit, I am using ```git.fetch()
      .setRemote(remote.getName())
      .setRefSpecs(remote.getFetchRefSpecs())
      .call();``` but it isnt able to save

Comment: Without further details it is hard to say why 'it isn't able to save'. As this question seems answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927163/jgit-checkout-a-remote-branch, I recommend to close this and create a new question, including an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I got the answer when the repo is cloned, it's only checking out a particular branch, and thus it isn't able to get references of other branches existing only in the remote when it has to switch. Thank you

Comment: See here how to fetch all branches while cloning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612910/jgit-not-cloning-all-branches or specify a list of known branches to clone with `CloneCommand::setBranchesToClone`. Note that branches need to be specified with their full ref, e.g. `refs/heads/foo`.